# C# Call Graph API with .Net Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, json, api, microsoft-teams

Hey im trying to post an http request (Create Teams online meeting) to the Graph API under c# .Net Framework 4.0 so i cannot use the Graph-SDK and i cannot use the System.net.http libary (no httpClient). I tried HttpWebRequest but im having difficulties with posting Json to the API.

My Request Function looks like this:

```
private string SendHttpRequest(string Method, string ContentType, WebHeaderCollection Headers, string Content, string URI)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);

                request.Method = Method;
                request.Headers = Headers;
                request.PreAuthenticate = true;
                request.ContentType = ContentType;

                StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
                requestWriter.Write(Content);
                requestWriter.Close();

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                string responseText = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                responseReader.Close();

                return responseText;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }
        }
```

And this works fine when my Content Type is text/xml(for a diffrent API) but not if its Application/Json.
I always get an Error 400 when i call `HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();`

Method = `"POST"`

ContentType = `"application/json"`

Headers = `Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + accessToken);`

Content = `string jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Content);`

URI = `"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings"`

Comment: What does the error specifically say? I remember Graph errors contain some additional information.

Comment: Which .net version you are using?

Comment: @jjczopek The Complete Error im getting is: Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (400) Ungültige Anforderung. This is German and simply says Bad Request. im sadly not getting more information

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT .Net Framework 4

Comment: Can you share the JSON payload you are sending?

Comment: Sure here is an example: {"startDateTime":"2020-06-16T10:45:00","endDateTime":"2020-06-16T13:00:00","subject":"JsonTest"}

Comment: I have found another clue. After checking this call in Postman in recived a more detailed 
Error.{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "onlinemeeting cannot be null.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-06-16T09:18:57",
      "request-id": "..."
    }
  }
}
And after some futher investigation i have found that my datetime format is diffrent.
Should be something like 2020-06-30T10:15:00.2444915-07:00 but mine is only 2020-06-16T13:00:00
Can someone Tell me how to convert that ?

Answer (score 0):

for anyone with the same difficulties.

I was missing the Timezones in my startDateTime and endDateTime.

To add those i had to Format my DateTime i recive from my database.

This worked for me:

```
TimeAndOffset = new DateTimeOffset(reservation.beginnUhrzeit,
   TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(reservation.beginnUhrzeit));
teamsCreate.startDateTime = TimeAndOffset.ToString("o");
```

reservation.beginnUhrzeit is my Database variable

teamsCreate is an Object i can later serialize to Json

After that everything worked.